# Professional games that ended with mate

Tags: history

What are some professional games where the losing side did not resign before receiving mate?

And how sure are people of the record? In old books they did not care much for complete historical accuracy, so a reference that makes the mate story believable would be better.

Comment: Related: http://chess.stackexchange.com/q/891/167

Comment: I don't see the point, very awesome games resign with forced mates while others don't... why would anybody be interested in just one half, while the other half is exactly the same?.. maybe you just want to filter out winning by material advantage, in hope to find games with awesome chain mates? if that is the case, there are ways to search them, just improve your search skills with google

Comment: @ajax333221 any suggestions on _how_ to improve your skills?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite a few games here. There are many games with top players that ended in mate.

http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chesscollection?cid=1001021

Answer (score 4):

Most of the games that end in checkmate are where the weak side allows checkmate for whatever reason (he thinks it's a nice win / checkmate, to ruin the publishability of the game, etc), but the strongest example I can think of where a player allowed mate on the board accidentally is Deep Fritz vs Kramnik:
http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1440796